# Storing 2D array (object) into a text file

Tags: python, file, file-handling

```
CustomerList = []
CustomerList.append (c1)
CustomerList.append (c2)
CustomerList.append (c3)
CustomerList.append (c4)
CustomerList.append (c5)

for c in CustomerList:
    print ("%8s %25s %35s %15s %15s" % (c.name, c.birth, c.address, c.hkid, "$"+str(c.balance)+"HKD"))
```

I have c1-5 values stored above, so I get the results as

```
Jack    Jan, 10th, 1996  430 Davis Ct., San Francisco     M8875895       $40000HKD
Smith  March 24th, 1997  3-5 Tai Koo Shing, Hong Kong     M3133242         $600HKD
Suzy      May 5th, 1995 32 Clearwater Bay Ave. Hong Kong  M8378644      $100000HKD
```

I get like this.

I want to store this information into a text file using file access.

What I was trying to do was to use

```
inputFile = open("Customer.txt","w")
inputFile.write (....)
```

I have no idea how I am supposed to include in the .... blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("Customer.txt","w") as f: #closes file automtically after loop ends
   for c in CustomerList:
     f.write("%8s %25s %35s %15s %15s \n" % (c.name, c.birth, c.address, c.hkid, "$"+str(c.balance)+"HKD"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the print statement with write, then write a newline and then close the file

```
inputFile = open("Customer.txt","w")

for c in CustomerList:
  inputFile.write("%8s %25s %35s %15s %15s" % (c.name, c.birth, c.address, c.hkid, "$"+str(c.balance)+"HKD"))
  inputFile.write('\n')

inputFile.close()
```

Comment: I got what you told me and applied to my code. I appreciate it. Btw, can I do the same thing for append? I have newly adding customers, which will have names of c6, c7, c8, ...

Comment: Yeah you can do it with append. `inputFile = open("Customer.txt","a")`